# How to stop a simulation that is lagging?

Tags: animation

Basic Situation: I let a simulation run, but maybe I put some settings too high. Every frame takes forever though it's still going. Every 15 frames or so it updates, but inbetween that it lags and I can't click anything.

How do I cancel the simulation/calculation without closing Blender and losing the progress it has made?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem a countless number of times. The solution I always use that usually works is pressing the "escape" key on my keyboard while the animation is playing. This almost always works for me, and I hope it works for you. It also apparently stops pointCache bakes when the interface is frozen.

Comment: Thank you, that instantly solved it! It does seem to happen very often, so I hoped there was an easy solution.

Comment: You are welcome